# How to initialize a char member variable of a class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having trouble assigning value to a character class member:

```
class Node
{
 public:
    char c;
};

void main(void)
{   
    Node *node;
    node->c = 'a';
}
```

Comment: `Node *node;` => `Node node;` and `node->c = 'a';` => `node.c = 'a';`

Comment: Assignment is *not* the same as initialization.

Answer (score 2):

You are not constructing a `Node` object before assigning values to it. Your `node` pointer is uninitialized.

```
void main(void)
{
    Node *node = new Node; // <-- add 'new'
    node->c = 'a';
    delete node; // <-- add this, too
}
```

Alternatively, create the `Node` object in automatic storage on the stack instead of dynamic storage in the heap. Let the compiler manage the memory for you.

```
void main(void)
{
    Node node; // <-- no pointer
    node.c = 'a';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are probably learning C++ I advice you do not manually control of object life duration in the C way and use C++ memory management features. In your simple example you are not constructing a `Node` object before assigning values to its members. Your pointer points to nowhere. If you use C++ features the compiler will be responsible for required memory allocation and freeing.

```
#include <memory>
void main(void)
{
    auto node = std::make_unique<Node>(); // allocate Node object in the dynamic memory
    node->c = 'a';
} // Node object automatically destroyed and frees dynamic memory
```

You can also direct the compiler to allocate `Node` object on function local stack.

```
void main(void)
{
    Node node; // Node object on stack
    node.c = 'a';
} // Node object automatically destroyed, stack memory is freed.
```